# Android NanoHTTPD Streaming content persistent connection

Tags: android, streaming, range, nanohttpd

I have been using NanoHTTPD in one of our apps to serve content, including Audio and Video from local SDCard to the Webview. The content range and content length headers along with the HTTP Status have been correctly configured. Now, we have a use case where we want to serve content on the server via NanoHTTPD.

The problem with the NanoHTTPD approach is that it reads the complete content that the Webview requests for. In case of a local file, it is still Ok, but you can't wait for it to fetch so much content from the server and flush the output stream.

I am looking for an approach where I am able to open a connection and keep serving a part of the data requested back. Just like it works when fetching content with range headers in request. The connection is kept open and Video player plays as soon as it has sufficient buffer.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using HTTP Client. I registered a pattern on localhost with unique port and handled the response for large media by adding appropriate headers, status and content length. Three things to do here:

1) Copy headers from HTTP response to the local response 
2) Set response code. Full content (200) or partial content (206) 
3) Create a new InputStreamEntity and add it to response

```
@Override
    public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        String range = null;
        //Check if there's range in request header 
        Header rangeHeader = request.getFirstHeader("range");

        if (rangeHeader != null) {
            range = rangeHeader.getValue();
        }

        URL url = new URL(mediaURL);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Http URL");
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //If range is present, direct HTTPConnection to fetch data for that range only    
        if(range!=null){
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Range",range);
        }
        //Add any custom header to request that you want and then connect.
        httpConn.connect();

        int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        //Copy all headers with valid key to response. Exclude content-length as that's something response gets from the entity. 
        Map<String, List<String>> headersMap =  httpConn.getHeaderFields();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headersMap.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey() != null && !entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("content-length")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                    response.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        //Important to set correct status code
        response.setStatusCode(statusCode);

        //Pass the InputStream to response and that's it.
        InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(httpConn.getInputStream(), httpConn.getContentLength());
        entity.setContentType(httpConn.getContentType());
        response.setEntity(entity);

    }
```